# How to get Duplicated Keys into one Key with all Key values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this following code, I have a list of Items:
Date: 0 GameId 0 GameValue 1
Date: 0 GameId 0 GameValue 2
Date: 0 GameId 1 GameValue 1
Date: 0 GameId 1 GameValue 1

And I want to loop all of the items to get this:

```
 $newArray[] = array($gameId => array($gameValue))
```

My Code :

```
foreach ($games as $ga) {
        $gamedId = $ga["gameId"];
        $gameValue = $k["gameValue"];
        $result[] = array($gameId => array($gameValue));
    };
```

What Can I do to remove all duplicate Ids and get all the Value with same Id?

Comment: `$result[$gameId][] = $gameValue`

Comment: Could you explain to me, why this works?

Comment: @TryHard11332 It works because you then collect by game id. Just play around with arrays - create `$abc = [];`, add some `$abc[] = 1;`, add some with associated key `$abc['my_key'] = 2;`, ... and then look at the result with `var_dump` or `var_export`.